# How can i improve the performance of the SQLite database?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite

**Background:** I am using SQLite database in my flex application. Size of the database is 4 MB and have 5 tables which are

1. table 1 have 2500 records
2. table 2 have 8700 records
3. table 3 have 3000 records
4. table 4 have 5000 records
5. table 5 have 2000 records.

**Problem:**  Whenever I run a select query on any table, it takes around (approx 50 seconds) to fetch data from database tables. This has made the application quite slow and unresponsive while it fetches the data from the table.

How can i improve the performance of the SQLite database so that the time taken to fetch the data from the tables is reduced?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could tell us **what structures** the table have and **what queries** you run over them? Probably the answer will be either of: *“use indexes”*, or *“rework on your queries”*. Also note that SQLite is spelled with one L and three leading capital letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I tell you in a comment, without knowing what structures your database consists of, and what queries you run against the data, there is nothing we can infer suggesting why your queries take much time.

However here is an interesting reading about indexes : [Use the index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/book/export/html/12). It tells you what an index is, how you should design your indexes and what benefits you can harvest.

Also, if you can post the queries and the table schemas and cardinalities (not the contents) maybe it could help.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using asynchronous or synchronous execution modes? The difference between them is that asynchronous execution runs in the background while your application continues to run. Your application will then have to listen for a dispatched event and then carry out any subsequent operations. In synchronous mode, however, the user will not be able to interact with the application until the database operation is complete since those operations run in the same execution sequence as the application. Synchronous mode is conceptually simpler to implement, but asynchronous mode will yield better usability.

The first time `SQLStatement.execute()` on a `SQLStatement` instance, the statement is prepared automatically before executing. Subsequent calls will execute faster as long as the `SQLStatement.text` property has not changed. Using the same `SQLStatement` instances is better than creating new instances again and again. If you need to change your queries, then consider [using parameterized statements](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=SQL_07.html#1084918).

You can also use techniques such as deferring what data you need at runtime. If you only need a subset of data, pull that back first and then retrieve other data as necessary. This may depend on your application scope and what needs you have to fulfill though.

Specifying the database with the table names will prevent the runtime from checking each database to find a matching table if you have multiple databases. It also helps prevent the runtime will choose the wrong database if this isn't specified. Do `SELECT email FROM main.users;` instead of `SELECT email FROM users;` even if you only have one single database. (`main` is automatically assigned as the database name when you call `SQLConnection.open`.)

If you happen to be writing lots of changes to the database (multiple `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statements), then consider wrapping it in a transaction. Changes will made in memory by the runtime and then written to disk. If you don't use a transaction, each statement will result in multiple disk writes to the database file which can be slow and consume lots of time.

Try to avoid any schema changes. The table definition data is kept at the start of the database file. The runtime loads these definitions when the database connection is opened. Data added to tables is kept after the table definition data in the database file. If changes such as adding columns or tables, the new table definitions will be mixed in with table data in the database file. The effect of this is that the runtime will have to read the table definition data from different parts of the file rather than at the beginning. The `SQLConnection.compact()` method restructures the table definition data so it is at the the beginning of the file, but its downside is that this method can also consume much time and more so if the database file is large.

Lastly, as [Benoit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/457352/benoit) pointed out in his comment, consider improving your own SQL queries and table structure that you're using. It would be helpful to know your database structure and queries are the actual cause of the slow performance or not. My guess is that you're using synchronous execution. If you switch to asynchronous mode, you'll see better performance but that doesn't mean it has to stop there.

The Adobe Flex documentation online has more information on [improving database performance](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=SQL_19.html#1084959) and [best practices working with local SQL databases](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=SQL_20.html#1085042).

Answer (score 0):

You could try indexing some of the columns used in the WHERE clause of your SELECT statements.  You might also try minimizing usage of the LIKE keyword.

If you are joining your tables together, you might try simplifying the table relationships.

Like others have said, it's hard to get specific without knowing more about your schema and the SQL you are using.